# Did Britain bill Poland for maintaining Polish Air Force that fought over Britain?

Tags: world-war-two, united-kingdom, poland, great-britain

> After the war, a bill for over 68 million pounds sterling, covering the equipment and operating costs of the Polish Air Force in Great Britain, was paid from the Polish gold reserves deposited in Canada.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Bank_of_Poland

This is an uncited claim in wikipedia; the claim is repeated word for word on multiple sites, but there is no source or reference for this claim.

Is there evidence to support or rebut the claim?

Comment: What makes you think this isn't true?

Comment: I admit it's a bit surprising, but if you're going to question Wikipedia and Google results, you have to provide some proof or reasons for it, as @SteveBird suggests.

Comment: This claim would be highly controversial in Poland, figure of 68 million pounds is often quoted but with no reliable sources. I'm hoping someone would come up with references.

Comment: Yes, I see this claim is not in the Polish Wikipedia article (not 100% sure because Google translator). And other sources repeat word by word what Wiki says in English. There maybe a case here.

Comment: @Brasidas Well, this is kind of "trivia" that's not really appropriate for an article about NBP at all. Would be more suited to articles about  "PL-GB relations" or "PAF in GB"

Comment: Australia and other dominions had to pay for the arms, equipment, supply of their troops serving under British command in ww1 and ww2. so it's hraly surprising that a seperate flagged Polish forces were billed for,

Comment: Looks like not inviting Polish pilots to the Victory Parade was enough

Answer (score 10):

It appears this war debt was partially voided.

> The Government of The United Kingdom will make no claim for replayment
>   of the Ł 73 million sterling, in respect of amounts spent on war
>   material, equipment, supplies, etc, for the Polish Armed Forces in the
>   West.
>
> The Government of the United Kingdom will leave in abeyance at present
>   the question of the repayment of the Military Credits amounting to a
>   further Ł 47 1/2 million sterling, expended on the salaries and pay of
>   the Polish Armed Forces in the West up to the 5 th July, 1945, but
>   reserve the right to reopen discussion of this question.

Source:

Treaty about finances between Poland and Great Britain and Northern Ireland, signed in London on June 24 1946.
http://isap.sejm.gov.pl/DetailsServlet?id=WDU19470630365

Comment: But isn't this in excess over the 68 million pounds paid in gold? I would quite expect to be so. Czechoslovakia also paid for its army and exile government. But it was more complicated (problems with German reparations which were cancelled) and it was settled in 1982. Czechoslovakia paid £24 mil, $81.5 mil and got back it's gold in return. http://www.fronta.cz/dotaz/financovani-cs-jednotek-ve-velke-britanii-zlaty-poklad